# Installing rethinking

Tags: r

I tried to follow McElreath's instructions for installing rethinking to the letter. Installing rstan and then below syntax (1) including restarting R every time he suggested. Got error (2) that I do not know how to resolve.
(1)

```
install.packages(c('coda','mvtnorm'))
options(repos=c(getOption('repos'),rethinking='http://xcelab.net/R'))
install.packages('rethinking',type='source')
```

(2)

```
ERROR: dependency 'shape' is not available for package 'rethinking'
* removing 'C:/Users/AACH4770/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/rethinking'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rethinking’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: Have you tried installing package `shape` by hand before installing `rethinking`?

Comment: Did now. Do I have reinstall rethinking once I have installed shape?

Comment: I am still getting:       

Error in library(rethinking) : there is no package called ‘rethinking’

Comment: Can you check your `.libPaths()`?

Comment: What does that mean? I am totally new...

Comment: Found below code on a different post. Helped me download successfully.

install.packages(c("mvtnorm","loo","coda"), repos="https://cloud.r-project.org/",dependencies=TRUE)
options(repos=c(getOption('repos'), rethinking='http://xcelab.net/R'))
install.packages('rethinking',type='source')

Comment: Yes, you need to reinstall `rethinking` after you've installed/updated dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It also works concurrently with a *slight* variation to your repos assignment. It being a named vector, the following works better:

```
install.packages("rethinking", 
                 repos=c(cran="https://cloud.r-project.org",
                         rethinking="http://xcelab.net/R"))
```

Oddly it does not *quite* make it. `shape` is still missing, but after explicitly installing `shape` and re-running the command above it works.